# Importing nested JSON documents into Elasticsearch and making them searchable

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash, finance, mongoexport

We have MongoDB-collection which we want to import to Elasticsearch (for now as a one-off effort). For this end, we have exported the collection with `monogexport`. It is a huge JSON file with entries like the following:

```
    {
     "RefData" : {
      "DebtInstrmAttrbts" : {
        "NmnlValPerUnit" : "2000",
        "IntrstRate" : {
          "Fxd" : "3.1415"
        },
        "MtrtyDt" : "2020-01-01",
        "TtlIssdNmnlAmt" : "200000000",
        "DebtSnrty" : "SNDB"
      },
      "TradgVnRltdAttrbts" : {
        "IssrReq" : "false",
        "Id" : "BMTF",
        "FrstTradDt" : "2019-04-01T12:34:56.789"
      },
      "TechAttrbts" : {
        "PblctnPrd" : {
          "FrDt" : "2019-04-04"
        },
        "RlvntCmptntAuthrty" : "GB"
      },
      "FinInstrmGnlAttrbts" : {
        "ClssfctnTp" : "DBFNXX",
        "ShrtNm" : "AVGO  3.625  10/16/24 c24 (URegS)",
        "FullNm" : "AVGO 3  5/8  10/15/24 BOND",
        "NtnlCcy" : "USD",
        "Id" : "USU1109MAXXX",
        "CmmdtyDerivInd" : "false"
      },
      "Issr" : "549300WV6GIDOZJTVXXX"
    }
```

We are using the following Logstash configuration file to import this data set into Elasticsearch:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/elastic/FIRDS.json"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    codec => json
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "_id", "path", "host" ]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
     hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
     index => "firds"
  }
}
```

All this works fine, the data ends up in the *index* `firds` of Elasticsearch, and a `GET /firds/_search` returns all the entries within the `_source` field.
We understand that this field is not indexed and thus is not searchable, which we are actually after. **We want make all of the entries within the original nested JSON searchable in Elasticsearch.**

We assume that we have to adjust the `filter {}` part of our Logstash configuration, but how? For consistency reasons, it would not be bad to keep the original nested JSON structure, but that is not a must. Flattening would also be an option, so that e.g.

```
"RefData" : {
      "DebtInstrmAttrbts" : {
        "NmnlValPerUnit" : "2000" ...
```

becomes a single key-value pair `"RefData.DebtInstrmAttrbts.NmnlValPerUnit" : "2000"`.

It would be great if we could do that immediately with Logstash, without using an additional Python script operating on the JSON file we exported from MongoDB.

**EDIT: Workaround**
Our current work-around is to (1) dump the MongoDB database to `dump.json` and then (2) flatten it with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) using the following expression, and finally (3) manually import it into Elastic

ad (2): This is the flattening step:

```sh
jq  '. as $in | reduce leaf_paths as $path ({}; . + { ($path | join(".")): $in | getpath($path) })  | del(."_id.$oid") ' 
    -c dump.json > flattened.json
```

**References**

- Walker Rowe: [ElasticSearch Nested Queries: How to Search for Embedded Documents](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/elasticsearch-nested-searches-embedded-documents/)
- [ElasticSearch search in document and in dynamic nested document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543091/elasticsearch-search-in-document-and-in-dynamic-nested-document)
- [Mapping for Nested JSON document in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30698466/mapping-for-nested-json-document-in-elasticsearch)
- [Logstash - import nested JSON into Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49555442/logstash-import-nested-json-into-elasticsearch)

**Remark for the curious:** The shown JSON is a (modified) entry from the [Financial Instruments Reference Database System (FIRDS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIRDS), available from the [European Securities and Markets Authority (ESMA)](https://www.esma.europa.eu/search/site/FIRDS) who is an European financial regulatory agency overseeing the capital markets.

Comment: Have you tried the `json` filter already? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html

Comment: @leandrojmp We are struggling with finding the correct way of doing that. We found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941739/using-json-with-logstash which gives examples (which however did not work).